# Python sqlite error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a sqlite database in python using sqlite3. Here i am creating new tables with names specified in `table_names` each having only one field column. `conn.execute('CREATE TABLE {} (quote TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);'.format(table_names[i]))` 
and `quote` i am reading from a file. However i am not able to execute insert statement and below i have posted what all i have tried and their errors. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO {} (quote) VALUES ('{}')'''.format(table_names[i], quote))
Error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

conn.execute('''INSERT INTO {} (quote) VALUES ('?')'''.format(table_names[i]), (quote,))
Error : sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

conn.execute('''INSERT INTO ? (quote) VALUES ('?')''', (table_names[i], quote))
Error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Comment: If you are trying to assign variable `foo` to the value in `bar`, do you do `foo = "bar"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter marker `?` must not be quoted, because in SQL, everything in quotes is a string.

The correct form is:

```
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO {} (quote) VALUES (?)'''.format(table_names[i]), (quote,))
```

Comment: But the value they are trying to add is a string.

Comment: The parameter's *value* is a string, the parameter itself is an abstract variable.